# Spring Cloud Contract Consumer | Mock OkHttp

Tags: groovy, spring-cloud-contract

I've my main class something like this:

```
class MyClass{

    String bar(String inputString){
        String url = "https:x.y.z/p/q";  //the URL is framed dynamically based on other class attributes
        final String payloadInJson = getPayload(inputString)
        final String response = doPostRequest(url, payloadInJson)
    }

    private static String doPostRequest(final String url, final String postData) throws IOException {
        final RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, postData)
        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build()
        final Response response = createOkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute()
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("...")
        }
        response.networkResponse().header("Location")
    }


    private static OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {
        Config config = new ConfigBuilder()
                .withTrustCerts(true)
                .build()
        def httpClient = HttpClientUtils.createHttpClient(config)
        httpClient = httpClient.newBuilder().authenticator(Authenticator.NONE).build()
        httpClient
    }

}
```

and My Consumer test case is:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL, ids = ["com.ex:foobar:+:stubs:8090"])
class MyClassTest{
     @Inject
     private MyClass myClass

     def 'happyPath'(){
         given:
         ...
         when:
            String res = myClass.bar('lorem...')
     }
}
```

Question is how to mock the OkHttp URL and use localhost?
Or is it that in the test case, I can refer the actual URL framed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Spring Cloud Contract, we start an HTTP server on a given or random port. It's enough for you to set you OK Http Client to point to the started server. Example

PSEUDOCODE:

```
class MyClass{
private String url = "https:x.y.z/p/q";

String bar(String inputString){
        final String payloadInJson = getPayload(inputString)
        final String response = doPostRequest(this.url, payloadInJson)
    }

// package scope
void setUrl(String url) {
this.url = url;
}
}
```

and in your test you can then set the stub's port and url

THE TEST (PSEUDOCODE AGAIN):

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL, ids = ["com.ex:foobar"])
class MyClassTest{
     @Inject
     private MyClass myClass

     @StubRunnerPort("foobar") int stubPort;

     def 'happyPath'(){
         given:
         myClass.url = "http://localhost:${stubPort}"
         when:
            String res = myClass.bar('lorem...')
     }
}
```

a better option is to use a proper `@Configuration` class where you define beans and inject the URL via constructor.  Anyways, hopefully, it shows you how you can approach the problem.

Comment: Basically, encapsulate what varies, isn't it? :)

Comment: Absolutely :) That way you can easily change that